# What are some fast outlier detection methods for big data in R?

Tags: r, outliers, large-data

I have a large dataset (300,000 rows) for which there are clear outliers.  Box plots of two of the DVs of interest reveal the presence of large numbers of outliers by the Tukey outlier detection rule (1.5 * IQR).  See image below:

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8O2y.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/31cJp.png
```

I don't feel comfortable eliminating such a large number of outliers, and yet conceptually a large number of the variables are clear errors (e.g. it doesn't make sense that people spend 24 hours a day sleeping).

I'm wondering two questions:

(1) What is the 'state of the art' outlier detection on big datasets?  I've come across six methods implemented in R ("HDo", "PCS", "BAC", "adjOut", "DDC", "MCD") all of which seem to yield very different results as to what constitutes an outlier (with little consensus across methods).

(2) If the answer is along the lines "you shouldn't be automatically detecting outliers... they need to be evaluated on a case by case basis", what are some clear diagnostics and visualization that one should do to justify eliminating outliers?

Comment: DBSCAN can do outlier detection on big, multivariate data. Cases that aren’t in a cluster are called “noise” or “outlier” points.

Comment: Mahalanobis distance can be used for this (multivariate).